# Create a page to set up global settings on portal with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, global-variables

I created a website and would like to know the best method to create a page for the global settings of the portal, such as the theme, logo, title, etc.

I would like a page for the setting that works like the dashboard of a Wordpress or any CRM that you can download, of course with much less functions. Things I'd like to change throughout the site could be: logo, the site title, meta tags, links of the portal for social etc.

Comment: Hey Alex, your issue is resolved or not? I have solution for you

Comment: Hy i'm trying to use and understand more with the example made on the first answer but if you have a new solution i'll be very happy because it will help me to learn a new method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create [modelless form](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html#)
2. Use [Configure::dump()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#Cake%5CCore%5CConfigure::dump) to store your settings in php or ini file
3. [Read this part of CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html), to learn how to read and use stored settings

**EXAMPLE:** (Note: This part of the code is used in my own Admin plugin)

1: Create modelless form

**src/Form/SiteForm.php**

```
<?php
namespace Admin\Form;

use Cake\Form\Form;
use Cake\Form\Schema;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\Core\Configure;

/**
 * Site Form.
 */
class SiteForm extends Form
{
    /**
     * Builds the schema for the modeless form
     *
     * @param Schema $schema From schema
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _buildSchema(Schema $schema)
    {
        return $schema;
    }

    /**
     * Form validation builder
     *
     * @param Validator $validator to use against the form
     * @return Validator
     */
    protected function _buildValidator(Validator $validator)
    {
        return $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Defines what to execute once the From is being processed
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _execute(array $data)
    {
        Configure::write('Site', $data);
        // 2. Use Configure::dump(),.. to save your settings as php array to
        // config/site_config.php
        Configure::dump('site_config', 'default', ['Site']);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**src/Controller/SettingsController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Admin\Controller;

use Admin\Controller\AppController;
use Admin\Form\SiteForm;
use Cake\Core\Configure;

/**
 * Settings Controller
 *
 */
class SettingsController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $site = new SiteForm();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($site->execute($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Flash->success('Success.');
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error('There was a problem submitting your form.');
            }
        } else {
            $this->request->data = Configure::read('Site');
        }
        $this->set('site', $site);
    }
```

**src/Template/Settings/index.ctp**

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create($site);
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('description');
echo $this->Form->input('keywords');
// ... add your input fields
echo $this->Form->button(__('Save'));
$this->Form->end() ?>
```

**in config/bootstrap.php add, to load site_config.php**

```
Configure::load('site_config', 'default');
```

**in your layout, views, controllers,.. use for example**

```
<title>
    <?= Configure::read('Site.title') ?>
</title>
```

Comment: The guides are very well documented but i don't understand them very well because i'm trying to make all from myself. Do you know where i can find an example?

Comment: Thank you very much, your example explained everything.